# Bug in Developer Story → Open Source → Import from GitHub

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, github

When adding a project in my profile via Developer Story→Open Source→Import from GitHub, when I click to add a project I own on GitHub, nothing happens, and I don't get any error or warning.

If anyone wants to checkout what project I am trying to add, it's [Pablo-No/Galery-Test](https://github.com/Pablo-No/Galery-test) (I meant gallery, just a typo when I renamed it a few weeks ago). It's a open source project to test service workers. My Stack Overflow profile is correctly connected with my GitHub Profile. So I think it must be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! I can't reproduce this. It's a bit slow, but it does seem to be working

Comment: When it didn't work, I waited a lot and it didn't worked.
Now it does work, I don't know what fixed it, should I close the question, @BenjaminHodgson?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was. If you're happy that it's working OK for you now I think we can consider it solved! :)

Comment: Should I do something additional, or you've done all the work?
In every case, @BenjaminHodgson, thanks for your help.

Comment: Let me check with my colleague @JNat to see if he needs me to do anything other than slap the `status-norepro` tag on it. Either way you don't need to do anything, I can do any necessary admin myself!

Comment: Thanks for answering, @BenjaminHodgson.